# Mac will not boot into OSX after installing windows 10

Tags: macos, mac, bootcamp, disk-utility

Please help me I'm completely desparate. I have tried to install Windows 10 and it completely messed up my macbook pro system, I cannot boot into my mac, and it's full with things I desperately need.

My OSX doesn't show up in the Macs start up when pressing "option". Also, Pressing "boot into os x" from windows doesn't work either but just boots into windows OS all over again.

Using internet recovery mode, I see in diskutility all the drives except the boot camp drive are unmounted and grey, and their names changed from "macintosh hd" etc that they were to default names, and they are impossible to mount.

Attached the screenshot of my disk utility, and of diskutil list, diskutil cs list (nothing) and -r show /dev/disk0

[image: disk utility]
[image: diskutil list]
[image: -r show /dev/disk0]

The mac system should be installed on the one labeled disk0s2.. I have no idea what's going on and how it happend

Comment: I'd restore from a backup and just try to install Windows again. This time, be very careful about which partition you select.

Comment: No backup, any other ideas?

Comment: Luckily it looks like you got out of a bad situation this time.  Next time you may not be so lucky.  In the future **always** make a backup before you make *any* change that could take down your system.  I even make backups before applying updates from Apple.  Time Machine is perfect for this and reloading the disk from a backup has saved me several times when things have unexpectedly gone wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GUID types for partitions 2 and 3 are wrong. The both current values are `DE94BBA4-06D1-4D40-A16A-BFD50179D6AC`, which indicates two "Windows Recovery Environment" partitions. The procedure given below can correct type partition types, but there is no guarantee the data (OS X) did not get overwritten while installing Windows.

1. Boot using Internet Recovery.
2. Enter the command given below to get the GPT partition data.

   ```
   gpt -r show /dev/disk0
   ```

   Below is an example of from my computer. Your output will be very
   different.

   ```
   gpt show: /dev/disk0: Suspicious MBR at sector 0
          start        size  index  contents
              0           1         MBR
              1           1         Pri GPT header
              2          32         Pri GPT table
             34           6         
             40      409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
         409640        2008         
         411648   394530816      2  GPT part - EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7
      394942464   394530816      3  GPT part - EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7
      789473280    97654784      4  GPT part - EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7
      887128064      262144      4  
      887390208   478769528      5  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
     1366159736     1269536      6  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
     1367429272   195995208         
     1563424480   388568960      7  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
     1951993440     1269544      8  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
     1953262984      262144      9  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
     1953525128           7         
     1953525135          32         Sec GPT table
     1953525167           1         Sec GPT header
   ```
3. From your output, you will need to record the `start` and `size`
   integer values for the rows with the `index` of 2 and 3.
4. Enter the following commands. Replace the values of `start` and
   `size` with the integer values you recorded for row with the `index`
   of 2.

   ```
   diskutil unmountDisk /dev/disk0
   gpt remove -i 2 /dev/disk0
   diskutil unmountDisk /dev/disk0
   gpt add -i 2 -b start -s size -t 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC /dev/disk0
   ```
5. Again, enter the following commands. Replace the values of `start`
   and `size` with the integer values you recorded for row with the `index` of
   3.

   ```
   diskutil unmountDisk /dev/disk0
   gpt remove -i 3 /dev/disk0
   diskutil unmountDisk /dev/disk0
   gpt add -i 3 -b start -s size -t 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC /dev/disk0
   ```
6. Try to boot to OS X.

Comment: first of all thanks. when I try to do it though, the second part (number 5), I get "error: no space available on device". Help? Now this number 2 doesn't exist any more and in disk utility, I see those 92GB as "free space". waiting for further suggestion to handle the error

Comment: current gpt -r show: ![link to photo of current situation](http://i.imgur.com/ShEANII.jpg)

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in Step 5. I made a correction. You will need to continue from where I indicated in Step 4. No harm was done.

Comment: Dear David you have officially saved my life. I Truly cannot thank you enough.